# Transforming a flat jsonb database record into multiple table records during ETL

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, etl, dbt

I am trying to figure out an efficient/scalable solution for the following problem:

For a online multi-page form, the application database stores each form page as a separate table linked by an id (project_id). Every data element within the form is stored as a flat key:val jsonb column which has no meaning on their own.

During the ETL process I would like to apply an underlying business logic model to map related key:val pairs together and then load into the correct logical table for analysis. E.g. From the flat jsonb load map correct elements that could be a 'House' object vs a 'Car'.

Is there a way to do this purely using SQL? Or some form or jinja templating with dbt..

Or, should I create some form of mapping document (YAML) and then load as a pandas/polars dataframe and loop through each record building objects and loading the results to the correct tables underneath an apply() function? - seems like to could be slow for many source records.

Thanks

Example YAML model:

```
-
    category: category_1
    modelName: model1
    type: form_data.key1.value
    date: form_data.key1_date.value
    comment: form_data.key1_comment.value
    includeNoneValue: False
-
    category: category_1
    modelName: model2
    type: form_data.key2.value
    date: form_data.key2_date.value
    comment: form_data.key2_comment.value
    includeNoneValue: False
-
    category: category_2
    modelName: model3
    type: form_data.key3.value
    date: form_data.key3_date.value
    comment: form_data.key3_comment.value
    includeNoneValue: False
```

Example jsonb 'form_data' column:

```
{ key1: val, key1_comment: val, key1_date: val, key2: val, key2_comment: val, key2_date: val, key3: val, key3_comment: val, key3_date: val }
```

[image]

Comment: Please set out your sample data as formatted text, rather than images   https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557

Comment: SQL-only? Maybe; generally, jsonb related functionalities tend to be implemented differently depending on the database manager. What would be the underlying database manager? PostgreSQL? MySQL? MSSQL?